Changing padding of a shape
I need to do a partially transparent layout with a completely tranparent rectangle in the middle. The best approach I found to do that was this suggestion, which worked pretty well. The problem is that I actualy needed this rectangle to be horizontal (as if the paddings were bigger vertically than horizontally). In the thread I mentioned they said it is possible to do that implementing the shapes programmatically, but I'm new to this language and I wasn't able to do that. So far I did this:
activity.xml has this layout:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pattern"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/hole_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
            </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

activity.kt has this code
        val frameLayout = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.hole_frame)
        val drawable = ShapeDrawable(RectShape())
        drawable.paint.color = -0x34000000
        drawable.paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        drawable.paint.strokeWidth = 200f
        frameLayout.background = drawable

which gives me this:

I already tried to set padding using drawable.setPadding but that didn't work. If you have a solution for that or any other way to do this rectangular "hole" in the middle of the layout I'd appreciate.

My approach - using only layout. No programming.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@color/semi_transparent_grey"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:background="@color/semi_transparent_grey"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="20"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="40"
                android:background="@color/semi_transparent_grey"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@color/semi_transparent_grey"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

You can see here nested ViewGroups and Views which widths and heights are regulated by their percantage weight.10%-80%-10% is width distribution in horizontal direction. 40%-20%-40% - in vertical direction inside inner stripe.
Of course, you can set your own values.


That worked, thanks

You are welcome! It was interestng task for me)
